# Back-up of all tables in a database as sql file

Tags: mysql, shell

I am trying to create a back-up of all tables in a large mysql database having all tables as .sql file, this is what I am trying:

```
`mysqldump -h localhost --user=username --password  --tab=/tmp/test 
db_name`
```

this is the error i get:

```
`Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'username@%' (using password: YES)" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'`
```

I have spent lot of time searching for a solution for this error but I could not find anyone that could solve the issue. 
Of course the directory test permissions are ok, I have already checked that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enter the password with command. Just enter,

mysqldump -h localhost -u username -p db_name > backup_file.sql

Then you will get a prompt to enter password. Enter that and it should do the trick.

Thanks

Comment: My command is already prompting for a password, if i remove --password it says: ` Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when trying to connect`

Comment: I think you need to add the following privileges to the user you are using for the dump
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ...;
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON `schemaname`.* TO 'localhost'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `schemaname`.* TO 'username'@'localhost';

Can you try this and find out?

Thanks

Comment: thank you @aritra, i have done what you suggested, now it creates only first table in database and returns this error:
`Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/test/a_ab_text.txt' (Errcode: 2)" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'`

Comment: Hi @papacico, its good that it worked so far, now for this issue, there might be multiple causes. Let us do one thing. First create the out file in the path mentioned i.e. /tmp/test/a_ab_text.txt.
Once you have created this file, next from the /tmp/test dir, do a
chmod 777 a_ab_text.txt to make it fully editable. Then try running the sql command again. Hope this helps :-)

Thanks

Comment: i have done what you say, now it writes as before the sql statement for first table of database in the file i have created, and then it returns the same error:
` Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file '/tmp/test/a_ab_text.txt' (Errcode: 2)" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'

the strange thing is that is creates a a_ab_text.sql file with sql code in it and it says that it can't write to a_ab_text.txt

Comment: This issue can be a result of a full dir, so in your case I think it is running out of freespace in tmp dir. Just run the following command and see how much free space is there in the /tmp dir

$df -h /tmp

It should give you something like this

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       102G   97G     0 100% /

You need to see how much is available. If there is very little space then you need to free up extra space on /tmp dir.

Comment: This is the result so i don't think that is the problem:
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop60683p1  197G   40G  148G  21% /

Comment: Can you try this -> SHOW VARIABLES like '%tmp%'; and see to which directory it is pointing? It should be /tmp and not something else. If that is the case, then we need to make sure /tmp is used by your MySQL operation.
Thanks

Comment: this solved the issue! However i don't quite understand why mysql is not allowed to write to any directory but /var/tmp, even creating a test directory in /var/tmp gave the save error but if i dump the tables in /var/tmp there are not any problems. Thank you very much !

Comment: Hey thats awesome :-) Yeah even I need to get to the bottom of this as to why it writes to /var/tmp directory. Ok see ya. Thanks for the points tho :-)